# Save reply or forward in Outlook Client sent mail

Tags: outlook, dynamics-crm-2011

When you create a new mail in from the `CRM` it's possible to use the Outlook form. This is nice because you get your standard signature and also the mail saved in the outlook sent folder.

But if you reply on a mail from `CRM` you will only get the `CRM` mail form and the reply will not be saved in your personal outlook sent folder. Is it possible to use the Outlook form in the `CRM` also for replies and forwards to get the mail saved in personal sent folder?

Answer (score 0):

The way you can achieve this is by placing a ribbon button on the email entity when clicked will call a function, say "OpenOutlookForm"

The body of this method can be like

```
function OpenOutlookForm(formId) {
Xrm.Page.ui.formSelector.items.get(formId).navigate();
}
```

This should do the trick for you. Let me know the results.

Comment: i have placed ribbon button on the email activity and called your function, i got this exception "Object doesn't support property or method 'navigate'"

Comment: try `Xrm.Page.ui.formSelector.getCurrentItem();` if this returns null then probably you have no other custom forms available.

Comment: On second note, what exactly is a `Outlook Form` that you are referring in the question?

Comment: Outlook form means when we configure CRM with outlook client and then open the existing email activity from the outlook. and reply that activity.

Comment: `Xrm.Page.ui.formSelector.getCurrentItem()`; yes i have no other custom form available i have checked.

Comment: i have passed `CrmParameter : PrimaryControlId` to a ribbon function, is it right?? for getting `formId`.